# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to create spring application. I am getting below error during starting the tomcat server. Can anyone please help me to find out the reason for this issue?

exception

```
May 03, 2016 12:01:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [cricketapp] in web application [/CricketApp] threw load() exception
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.io.ResourceEditor.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader;Lorg/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver;)V
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1282)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1195)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5610)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>CricketApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>CricketApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0-Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0-Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.openxma</groupId>
            <artifactId>dsl-platform</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>  

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

my spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cricketapp" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/**" /> 

    <bean  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"    id="entityManagerFactory">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
      <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.cricketapp.domain" />
      <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
      </property>
      <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
    </bean>



    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"  id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"  transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cricketapp" />
      <property name="username" value="root" />
      <property name="password" value="root" />
   </bean>


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: You are mixing Spring 4.2.5 and 2.5 never mix versions of a framework.

Comment: Deinum - thanks for the response. are you referring spring-test version. I have removed that version now. still facing same issue

Comment: Do a `mvn dependency:tree` check the versions of the different spring jars. Something is pulling in a conflicting version somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

You should check your dependencies. One problem is your `spring-test` dependency: it has an old incompatible version and it is not in scope test!

The `ResourceEditor`changed between 2.5 and 4.2, the old constructor [ResourceEditor(ResourceLoader)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.5/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceEditor.html) is no longer available but instead [ResourceEditor(ResourceLoader,PropertyResolver)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceEditor.html).

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

In your current setup I would assume you will have two versions of Spring framework (2.5 and 4.2.5) in your dependencies. Have a look using `mvn dependency:tree` before and after changing the `spring-test` dependency above.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a doupt on your dependecies, I recommand to build a web project skeleton from https://start.spring.io/, import it to your workspace and check the Dependency Hiearchy tab of your `pom.xml`.

See the example: [inputs to generate a spring mvc 4.2.5 tomcat 7 project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUDmE.png) test, hibernate... are included
The configs, even your `web.xml` are initialized by annotations. you can avoid the spring-servlet by initializing through annotation,
Exmanple Hibernate:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.yourpackage.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {`` 

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.yourpackage.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

For the viewResolver:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.yourpackage")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Use the Dependency Hiearchy as a reference to be sure you're not missing any dependency.
For tomcat you can omit the dependecies since you have your localown server.